# Is this a correct natural deduction proof?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

Prove $ A \rightarrow B \vdash \neg (A \wedge \neg B)$

1. $A \rightarrow B \quad\quad\quad\quad$ Premise
2. $(A \wedge \neg B) \rightarrow B \quad \rightarrow $I, subcomputation below

$\quad\quad$ 2.1 $ A \wedge \neg B \quad $ Assumption
$\quad\quad$ 2.2 $ A \quad\quad\quad$ (2.1), $\wedge$E
$\quad\quad$ 2.3 $ B \quad\quad\quad$ (2.2)(1), $\rightarrow$E

3. $(A \wedge \neg B) \rightarrow \neg B \quad \rightarrow$I, subcomputation below

$\quad\quad$ 3.1 $A \wedge \neg B \quad$ Assumption
$\quad\quad$ 3.2 $\neg B \quad\quad\space\space$ (3.1), $\wedge$E

4. $\neg (A \wedge \neg B) \quad\quad\space\space$ (2)(3), $\neg$I

Comment: It looks ok to me.

Comment: An alternative approach is to recognize that $A \rightarrow B$ is **exactly** equivalent to $\;$ (not $A$) or $B.$

Comment: Why two subproofs ? It is enough to assume $A \land \lnot B$ and derive both $B$ and $\lnot B$ from it. Thus, you have a contradiction and the conclusion follows.

Comment: Not exactly...1) assume $A \land \lnot B$ and use Conjunction Elim to unpack it: 2) $A$ and 3) $\lnot B$. With 2) and the premise derive $B$ and you have the sought contradiction. Then conclude by Negation Intro with $\lnot (A \land \lnot B)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So I can use the $\neg$ Introduction rule ($ A \rightarrow B, A \rightarrow \neg B \vdash \neg A$)

Comment: Some systems allow you to derive both conditionals from one subproof.  Some require two.  You to use the one you are allowed to use.

Comment: Should I edit the question to add the rules I'm using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the inference system used in the proof, the answer is correct.

Please see @F. Zer answer for a proof using the Fitch Natural Deduction system.

Answer (score 5):

As Mauro points out in the comments, there is no need to start two subproofs. Instead, you can use the rule of **Negation Introduction** by assuming $A \land \lnot B$ and trying to reach a contradiction ($\bot$).

A possible proof using Fitch Natural Deduction system, could be:
$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\def\Ae#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ai#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall I} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ee#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ei#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists I} \: #1 \\}
\def\R#1{\qquad\mathbf{R} \: #1 \\}
\def\ci#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ce#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land E} \: #1 \\}
\def\oi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\lor I} \: #1 \\}
\def\oe#1{\qquad\mathbf{\lor E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ii#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ie#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to E} \: #1 \\}
\def\be#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow E} \: #1 \\}
\def\bi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow I} \: #1 \\}
\def\qi#1{\qquad\mathbf{=I}\\}
\def\qe#1{\qquad\mathbf{=E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ne#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ni#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg I} \: #1 \\}
\def\IP#1{\qquad\mathbf{IP} \: #1 \\}
\def\x#1{\qquad\mathbf{X} \: #1 \\}
\def\DNE#1{\qquad\mathbf{DNE} \: #1 \\}
$

**Hint:**

$$
\fitch{1.\,A \to B}{
 \fitch{2.\,A \land \lnot B}{
 3.\,A \ce{2}
 \vdots\\
 6.\,\bot
}\\
7.\,\lnot(A \land \lnot B) \ni{2-6}
}
$$

**Solution:**

> $$\fitch{1.\,A \to B}{ \fitch{2.\,A \land \lnot B}{ 3.\,A \ce{2} 4.\,B \ie{1,3} 5.\,\lnot B \ce{2} 6.\,\bot \ne{4,5}}\\7.\,\lnot(A \land \lnot B) \ni{2-6}}$$

Comment: Thanks, whilst this does make sense to me. The set of rules I'm using don't allow this. Assumptions can only be made with $\rightarrow$ Introduction. The assumption being the hypothesis of the implication and the conclusion of the sub-proof being the conclusion of the implication.

Comment: I am wondering if this system I'm working with has a name like the Fitch notation you just showed.

Comment: Are you using a book ? Class notes ?

Comment: Class notes. No name given other than 'Natural Deduction'. At the moment it's just a basic set with 1 elimination and 1 introduction rule for each of {$\neg, \wedge, \vee, \rightarrow$}

Comment: On a tangent, those systems that require you to prove $\Gamma, P \vdash Q$ and $\Gamma, P \vdash \lnot Q$ to conclude $\Gamma \vdash \lnot P$, instead of just allowing you to show $\Gamma, P \vdash \bot$, remind me of the chess rules defining the win condition to be checkmate, instead of defining the win condition as "capture the opponent's king".  i.e. it stops one step short of what I view as the real goal.  (Modulo the situations in the chess case where the official definition would result in a draw whereas the simplified definition would result in a win.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler Ha, unfortunately I have no choice in matter :/